# How can I add one new class to MS COCO dataset and do transfer learning to achieve more classes?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, transfer-learning, coco

I've annotated new image with new class according to the approach is recommended by http://www.immersivelimit.com/tutorials/create-coco-annotations-from-scratch
then I combined new class annotations with coco json annotate files and create TFrecord by running
create_coco_tf_record.py from this repository : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools
then I retrained faster_rcnn_resnet101 which its pretrained model is available in Tensorflow Model Zoo. I did retrain process according to this tutorial: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10
the problem is that the loss curve didn't converge and also had oscillation!!
how can I do to get better result from retraining models?

Comment: Your learning rate might be to large, try a smaller learning rate.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I tried this solution and the results didn’t change! What can I do more?